# Using duality to establish a relationship between in two-stage linear programming

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I'm currently working on a problem that involves a two-stage linear program (LP). For simplicity, I refer to the LP in first stage as LP$_1$, and the LP in the second stage as LP$_2$. The relationship between the LPs in this problem is that the feasible region of LP$_2$ depends on the optimal solution of LP$_1$.

I am wondering whether anything can be said about the relationship between the norm of optimal value to LP$_2$ and the norm of another parameter that intuitively represents the "slope" between the optimal value of LP$_2$ and the optimal solution of LP$_1$.

My explanation is a little confusing, so I've written it as formally as possible below.

### Formulation

- Let $\widehat{x}$ be an $(N_x \times 1)$ vector that represents the optimal solution to LP$_1$. We assume that this value is fixed.
- Let $Q(\widehat{x})$: $\mathbb{R}^{N_x}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that represents the optimal cost of LP$_2$ in terms of $\widehat{x}$, the optimal solution to LP$_1$
- Let $\nabla Q(\widehat{x})$ represents the subgradient of the function $Q$ at $\widehat{x}$. This term essentially represents the "slope" between the optimal objective value of LP$_2$ and the optimal solution to LP$_1$.

We express the primal of LP$_2$ as,

\begin{alignat}{4}
\begin{aligned}
z_{primal}       =  &\min_{y}      & c^\text{T} y &                \\
                    &\mbox{ s.t.}  & A y          & \geq b - W\widehat{x} \\
                    &              &        y          & \geq   0  
\end{aligned}
\end{alignat}

And express the dual of LP$_2$ as,

\begin{alignat}{2}
\begin{aligned}
z_{dual}      = &\max_{\lambda}  & ( b - & W\widehat{x} )^\text{T} \lambda\\
                &\mbox{ s.t.}   &A\lambda   & \leq c  \\
     &               & \lambda       & \geq   0
\end{aligned}
\end{alignat}

We assume that a optimal solution exists for both the primal and the dual, so that $Q(\widehat{x}) = z_{primal} = z_{dual}$ by duality. We also the dual formulation can be used to show that $\nabla Q(\widehat{x}) = \lambda^\text{T} W$.

Then,

\begin{alignat}{1}
\begin{aligned}
z_{primal}      &= z_{dual} \\ 
Q(\widehat{x})    &= z_{dual} \\ 
Q(\widehat{x})   &= (b - W\widehat{x})^\text{T} \lambda \\ 
Q(\widehat{x})    &= b^\text{T}\lambda - (W\widehat{x})^\text{T} \lambda \\ 
Q(\widehat{x})   &= b^\text{T}\lambda - \lambda^\text{T} (W\widehat{x}) \\ 
Q(\widehat{x})    &= b^\text{T}\lambda - \lambda^\text{T} W \widehat{x} \\ 
Q(\widehat{x})   &= b^\text{T} \lambda -  \nabla Q(\widehat{x}) \widehat{x} \\ 
|Q(\widehat{x})|   &= |b^\text{T}\lambda -  \nabla Q(\widehat{x})\widehat{x} |
\end{aligned}
\end{alignat}

At this point, I'm wondering whether it is fair to say that $|Q(\widehat{x})|$ is "roughly proportional" to $|\nabla Q(\widehat{x})|$. If so, why? If not, why not? In addition, I'm wondering whether anything at all can be said about the relationship between these two values as the problem is currently formulated.